# net core 3.1 runtime backword compatibility with 2.2

Tags: .net-core, runtime

I have a host with .net core 2.2 runtime installed and a number of net core applications. If I install .net core 3.1 runtime without recompiling/migrating my applications would this break them?

Comment: that would make developing of different versions very difficult... they can of cause be installed at the same time. however if you have many cross project dependencies and you want to update one to a newer version, you will have to update all projects to stay compatible

Comment: @PatrickBeynio you are absolutely right. But my goal is to add new application targeted 3.1 and not break already hosted with 2.2